# Having dynamic sql in my select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a dynamic content questionnaire and I have controls that need to be propulated with SQL?

I was trying to select from the table `Questionnaire` and run a SQL statement stored in the `PrepopulateContentSQL" column below. The query returns a single value.

Ex:

```
Select name from Agency
```

My table `Questionnaire`:

```
QuestionID int 
Required bit
Data_Type int
Control_Type int 
Data_Choices nvarchar
Data_Max_Length int  
Question_Group_Id int
Question_Label nvarchar
Question_Order int  
PrepopulateContentSQL nvarchar
PrePopulated bit
```

I was thinking maybe a function?

```
Select 
    QuestionID, Required, Control_Type, Data_Choices, 
    GetPrepopulated(PrepopulateContentSQL) As PreValue
From 
    Questionnaire
```

Comment: I read functions are not best solutions what are alternatives?

Comment: It's not that functions are bad solutions; it's that mis-used functions are bad solutions.

Comment: @Chaka . . . What is your question?  For many purposes, a function is exactly the right solution for what you want to do.

Comment: If I implement it as a function, I need a example

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to be storing that sql string to be executed each time?  If they're as simple as "select name from agency" I imagine that they could just as easily be implemented as a macro-like system where you would predefine a number of queries, and instead the pre-populate column could simply hold a reference.

This would give you a little more security (as you no longer need to worry too much about the contents of that sql) and perhaps give you scope to customise the UI to show @AgencyName rather than 'select name from agency'

Just a thought...

Comment: I don't completely follow, can you give me an example?

Comment: Well, lets say you only have 2 queries that are used in pre-populated fields "select name from agency" and "select last_billed from agency". By storing the raw sql, you risk having a value of "delete * from agency" as well... If instead your table has a 'prepopulate_query_id' column, your application simply has to map those 2 queries to id's 1 and 2 and implement them as appropriate.